# Writing Comparators in C

Tags: c, struct, comparator

Is there a way to overload the comparators in C so that we can compare structs using `>`, `=`, and `<`

For example:

```
struct point {
    int x, y;
}

struct point pt1 = make_point(2, 4);
struct point pt2 = make_point(2, 3);
```

we could have it compare on the `y` value (or some arbitrary member of the struct).

```
if (pt1 > pt2)
{
printf("Point 1 is greater than Point 2\n");
}
```

and it would print out, `Point 1 is greater than Point 2` since 4 > 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. This is a C++ feature.

You should write some function, that does this and use it like: `if( is_greater( pt1, ptr2 ) )` something like this.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot overload operators in C. You cannot even overload ordinary *functions* in C.

Answer (score 1):

No, C does not support operator overloading. The best you can have is writing a comparator function.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said C does not support operator overloading. This kind of programming paradigm is usually accomplished in C by passing a comparator operation using a function pointer. For example see [qsort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/) in the standard library.